# Is there a way for a Hex Channeler Witch to gain access to the Displacement spell?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, witch

Is there a way for a [Witch](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/) with the [Hex Channeler](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/archetypes/paizo-witch-archetypes/hex-channeler) archetype to have [Displacement](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/displacement/) on her spell list?

For my purpose, I'm dealing with an NPC. I can make changes to the Witch Patron, Feats, Skills, and Archetypes (as long as she retains the Hex Channeler's ability to channel negative energy offensively). However, I can't change the NPC's gear much - if the PCs kill her, they'll get enough gear without adding a Ring of Spell Storing on top of everything else.

While I could just give a witch the spell via GM fiat, I don't want to in this case. My players are very interested in character builds and are likely to ask how the NPC worked. Since one or more PCs might die in the fight, I'd prefer to avoid answering "it's not really possible".

Comment: Assuming you don’t want “you’re the GM, just say this witch has _displacement_,” you should probably note that as an unacceptable answer. Questions like this often attract such answers even when they explicitly request otherwise.

Comment: Is it important that the witch has access to Displacement specifically, or would it still be useful to list ways to gain other spells that grant miss chance?

Answer (score 2):

### Make them a Samsaran.

The [Samsaran](https://www.aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Samsaran) alternate racial trait Mystic Past Life says:

> **You can add spells from another spellcasting class to the spell list of your current spellcasting class.** You add a number of spells equal to 1 + your spellcasting class’s key ability score bonus (Wisdom for clerics, and so on). The spells must be the same type (arcane or divine) as the spellcasting class you’re adding them to. For example, you could add divine power to your druid class spell list, but not to your wizard class spell list because divine power is a divine spell. These spells do not have to be spells you can cast as a 1st-level character. The number of spells granted by this ability is set at 1st level. Changes to your ability score do not change the number of spells gained. This racial trait replaces shards of the past.

By using this, the witch could poach from another class's spell list (wizard is the best choice), and add Displacement to their list, along with other suitable spells.